# Unable to write to MS SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I set up MS SQL Server 2017 Express.

It is fine to use `pyodbc` to read existing table data.

However, when I created tables, inserted data to tables, the python program finished with no errors.

However, when I refreshed the tables on with MS SQL Management Studio, an error appeared `Lock request time out period exceeded` as shown below.

When I executed `select * from mytable`, its status kept on `Executing query`.

How to solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when a query doesn't get a response from a locked resource. End the session ID which has a lock on the table.

Use the management tools to find the active operations that are stalled and kill them. This should free up the table for future queries.

For future applications, when you begin a transaction make sure there is a matching "commit", this is a really common error when the closing operation results in a prompt that has to be manually closed rather than exiting as expected.